# Check class of object at runtime

Tags: d

I have some inheritance classes, say `A` and `B: A`.
I found a way how to check at **runtime**, which class am i dealing with:

```
A a = new A;
if( some condition )
  a = new B;

if (a.classinfo.name == "a.b")
  writeln("That previous condition was met");
```

However is there a better way? I am really confused by now with `typeid` `typeof` and `is`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to know if it's that type or any subtype of it, which is probably the best plan in these situations:

```
(cast(B)a) !is null
```

If you need to know an exact type, which is rare, you can use:

```
a.classinfo is B.classinfo
```